# No Bluetooth permissions granted when coding the example app from Android developer

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, android-instant-apps, android-studio-3.5

Sorry, that questions sound stupid but drives me crazy.
I'm about implementing an app very similar to the Bluetooth App described in Developer Android.

I don't get required permissions, though.

Yes, I ask for permission twice
a) in my manifest

b) and I check before using BT with 
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(..)

In logcat, see belove, I learn that my app doesn't get Bluetooth permission.

It isn't the first time I write a BT app. LAst time it was fine. But was a while ago.

My mobile (Nexus 5) told me something about Development Mode Active and apps would be routed to Developer Manager to be started as instant app.

I also learned that Bluetooth access is not granted to instant apps at all.
(I understand that.).

Could that be the problem? Does Android Studio produce different apps now. Does it interact in a different manager with the test hardware?

If so, how do I pursuade Android Studio to *not* produce an instant app?

Thank you so much in advance.

```
my manifest code
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Log output:
android.permission.BLUETOOTH: denied

and some lines earlier

I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/.permissions.GrantPermissionsTrampoline (has extras)} from uid 10029 on display 0
W/Isotope: UID: [10029]  PID: [14812] GrantPermissionsTrampoline : Permission not allowed: android.permission.BLUETOOTH
```

Comment: are you making an instant app? If not, by any chance did you check do not show again and deny the permission previously?

Comment: If it's instant, yes it will be denied... always denied

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering you... It was so easy. I have just deactivated that instant apps dev manager on my Android phone.

Voila, my app is an app again and no instant app. It gets all 
permissions it need. Anything is fine.

I'm sorry again.